# How to create array with all the names (or IDs) of all textareas on an html page?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I create an array containing all the names (or the IDs) of all the textareas present in an html page? I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
 $arrayTextAreasNames = [];
    var listFields = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
    for(var i = 0; i < listFields.length; i++) 
    {
        if(listFields[i].type == 'textarea')
        {
            $arrayTextAreasNames[] = listFields[i].name; //Empty!
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> var listFields = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
> ```

You could avoid the filtering step by using `'textarea'` instead of `'*'`.

> ```
> listFields[i].type == 'textarea'
> ```

`type` is a property found on `<input>` elements (among a few others). It doesn't describe the element type. You are looking for the `tagName` property.

> ```
> $arrayTextAreasNames[] = listFields[i].name; //Empty!
> ```

JavaScript is not PHP. You need to use the `push` method to add things to an array, not assign them to an unnamed property.

```js
var arrayTextAreasNames = [];
var listFields = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
for (var i = 0; i < listFields.length; i++) {
    arrayTextAreasNames.push(listFields[i].name);
}
console.log(arrayTextAreasNames);
```

```html
<textarea name="foo"></textarea><textarea name="bar"></textarea>
```

Comment: It's also worth noting that for most use cases, moving the elements from an HTMLCollection into a 'proper' Array is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `Array.prototype.map` to HTMLCollection using `call` or `apply`:

```js
const t = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
// use 'map' for any iterable
const map = arr => fn => Array.prototype.map.call(arr, fn);

const names = map(t)(x => x.name);
const ids = map(t)(x => x.id);

console.log(names)
console.log(ids)
```

```html
<textarea name="one" id="1" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<textarea name="two" id="2" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<textarea name="three" id="3" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<textarea name="four" id="4" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<textarea name="five" id="5" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Swap `const` to `var` for older browsers.

Comment: Cool approach, you really got to what he was trying to do despite what he asked for. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
var tAreaList = [];
var tAreas = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");

Array.prototype.slice.call(tAreas).forEach (function (tArea) {
  tAreaList.push(tArea.id)
})
```

[JSBin Link](http://jsbin.com/nudoqijoqu/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score -2):

```
var listFields = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
```

read this document for more

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/getElementsByTagName

Comment: getElementsByTagName doesn't return an array

Comment: No, this will return the item with tag "textarea".

Comment: Which isn't what the question is asking for.

Comment: I want the loop to read and add to the array all the names or IDs of each textarea, without having to specify them one by one